# How do I use URLs of images from a text file in a javascript slideshow?

Tags: php, javascript, html, slideshow

I'm creating a slideshow where I'm displaying images based on their urls. I've used PHP to extract the image urls from web pages and I've used JavaScript to display them in a slideshow format. Only thing is, the first picture takes a lot of time to load so I decided to cache the urls by storing them in a text file, but I don't know how to read the urls from the text file in my JavaScript bit?

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how I should proceed. I couln't find anything helpful online.

My JS code is like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1">
        var slideimages=new Array() 
        slideshowimages("<?php echo join("\", \"", $image_urls); ?>") <--this is where I was initially echoing the array or image urls from php, but it proves slow for the first few images
        function slideshowimages(){
            for (i=0;i<slideshowimages.arguments.length;i++){
                slideimages[i]=new Image()
                slideimages[i].src=slideshowimages.arguments[i]
            }
        }
        var slideshowspeed1=30000

        var whichimage1=0
        function slideit1(){
            if (!document.images)
                return
            document.images.slide1.src=slideimages[whichimage1].src
            if (whichimage1<slideimages.length-1)
            whichimage1++
            else
                whichimage1=0
            setTimeout("slideit1()",slideshowspeed1)}slideit1()
  </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you intend to store the text file? At the user end? Then consider isolated storage introduced in HTML5. If at the server-side, it would not give you any performance boost. In fact, storing URLs locally will not give it to you either. You should make sure the pictures are in browser cache.

Comment: @Aneri: How do I make sure they are in the browser cache? And I'm using close to a 1000 images, so will the browser cache be able to hold all of them? Or is it sufficient if the browser cache just holds all of their urls?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you pulling from an external website? You generally will get a lot more speed if you pull them locally. I do believe that once it pulls the images once or so, it will cache for users when it shows up again. What you could do is to use that list you pull and create the images hidden on the page so they load with the page. Then when going through the slideshow, the user should have had time to cache the images and the slideshow will have sped up.

Just make a CSS class known as hidden and `visability:hidden;`it. Most browsers will still try to load the data.